# VB .NET Better way to write this code

Tags: vb.net

Just to give some more information for the below code, PickUpTime is a string and needs to be formatted like I have. GetRandom(int, int) generates a random number that includes the first number but excludes the second number. It is used for submitting a web form that I have no control over. The days at the beginning are basically store hours and can only pick a time between those hours. The final string can only be like "8:00 AM" or "8:30 AM".

```
Saturday 9am-3pm
Sunday 11am-5pm
Weekdays 8am-6pm
```

I am simply looking for a more efficient way of writing this code. I have been staring at it for awhile thinking there has to be a way, but I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated. The code does work in its current state. I am just looking to learn better coding practices.

```
If Date1.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
    i = GetRandom(2, 15)
ElseIf Date1.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
    i = GetRandom(6, 19)
Else
    i = GetRandom(0, 21)
End If
If i=0 Then
    PickUpTime = "8:00 AM"
ElseIf i=1 Then
    PickUpTime = "8:30 AM"
ElseIf i=2 Then
    PickUpTime = "9:00 AM"
ElseIf i=3 Then
    PickUpTime = "9:30 AM"
ElseIf i=4 Then
    PickUpTime = "10:00 AM"
ElseIf i=5 Then
    PickUpTime = "10:30 AM"
ElseIf i=6 Then
    PickUpTime = "11:00 AM"
ElseIf i=7 Then
    PickUpTime = "11:30 AM"
ElseIf i=8 Then
    PickUpTime = "12:00 AM"
ElseIf i=9 Then
    PickUpTime = "12:30 PM"
ElseIf i=10 Then
    PickUpTime = "1:00 PM"
ElseIf i=11 Then
    PickUpTime = "1:30 PM"
ElseIf i=12 Then
    PickUpTime = "2:00 PM"
ElseIf i=13 Then
    PickUpTime = "2:30 PM"
ElseIf i=14 Then
    PickUpTime = "3:00 PM"
ElseIf i=15 Then
    PickUpTime = "3:30 PM"
ElseIf i=16 Then
    PickUpTime = "4:00 PM"
ElseIf i=17 Then
    PickUpTime = "4:30 PM"
ElseIf i=18 Then
    PickUpTime = "5:00 PM"
ElseIf i=19 Then
    PickUpTime = "5:30 PM"
ElseIf i=20 Then
    PickUpTime = "6:00 PM"
End If

WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Time").SetAttribute("value", PickUpTime)
```

Comment: Use a dictionary where the key is what you have in `i` and the value is your PickUpTime`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about improving working code, and therefore belongs on [codereview.se]. This site is about problems with non-working code.

Comment: @ken-white Sorry about that. I am new and honestly was not aware of that site. Thank you for linking it to me though!

Comment: You could improve this code by using C# instead of VB.NET. :c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dt As DateTime = New DateTime(2015, 9, 1, 8, 0, 0)
dt = dt.AddHours(i * 0.5)
Dim PickupTime As String = dt.ToString("h:mm tt")
```

Hopefully.. this approach would be easier to read and maintain

Answer (score 1):

Completing my response - though, achan answer is most readable and makes sense:

```
Dim formattedTime As String
' Setting meridiem
If i < 8 Then
    formattedTime = "AM"
Else
    formattedTime = "PM"
End If

' Setting minutes
If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
    formattedTime = ":00 " & formattedTime
Else
    formattedTime = ":30 " & formattedTime
End If

' Setting hours
If i <= 9 Then
    formattedTime = (i + 16) \ 2 & formattedTime
Else
    formattedTime = (i - 8) \ 2 & formattedTime
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I like how you did it. For a beginner, your method works if you don't know the formatting commands like achan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the giant If starting with If i = 0 .... with the following:

```
PickupTime = New DateTime(2000, 1, 1, (i+16) \ 2, 30 * (i Mod 2), 0).TimeOfDay.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

define an array of String, then get the value according the index generating from random function.

```
Dim array(n) As String
    array(0) = "8:00 am"
    .....
    array(n) = "6:00 pm"

If Date1.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
    i = GetRandom(2, 15)
ElseIf Date1.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
    i = GetRandom(6, 19)
Else
    i = GetRandom(0, 21)
End If

formattedTime = array(i)
```